# Spring @RequestMapping value annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to learn that is there any difference between `@RequestMapping(/home)` and `@RequestMapping(value="/home")`

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Spring , both are same. The first one is used when only one url maps to a path.

`@RequestMapping("/home")` will map the urls:
 `<hostname>:<port>/home` to the class or method on which the annotation has been applied.

The second one is used when you have more urls to map to same path.
`@RequestMapping(value="/home")` will do the same as first one. but

`@RequestMapping(value = {
        "/home",
        "/someotherurl",
        "/moreUrl"
    })`

will map the following url:

`<hostname>:<port>/home
 <hostname>:<port>/someotherurl
 <hostname>:<port>/moreUrl`

to the method or class on top of which the annotation is applied.

Refer: https://dzone.com/articles/using-the-spring-requestmapping-annotation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `@RequestMapping("/home")` not `@RequestMapping(/home)` then no, there is no difference.

For annotations with a property named `value` this is also assumed to be the default and can be passed into the annotation definition without reference to `value=`. However, this is only valid if you want to define a single property. Otherwise the `value=` is required.

e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Sorry yes I meant @RequestMapping("/home"). Thanks a lot.